# Fabric.js 1.5 image clipto

Tags: fabricjs

I'm using Fabric.js to draw an image on canvas and then draw a rectangle when clicking down and moving mouse.

I want to crop the image using the rectangle.

When invoking the `clipTo()` function, I found Fabric.js doesn't clip the image from the specified position. It seems `x:0, y:0` actually indicates the central point of the image instead of top left corner of the image.

If I use the code below, I'll only get bottom right part of the image.

```
object.clipTo = function (ctx) {
    ctx.rect(0, 0, 700, 700);
};
```

Does anyone know how to calculate the correct start point (x, y)?

Answer (score 1):

This happen because when clipping the current transform is positioned on center of object.

To avoid this, change your clipTo function as follow:

```
object.clipTo = function (ctx) {
     ctx.save();
     ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
     ctx.rect(0, 0, 700, 700);
     ctx.restore();
};
```

Basically you reset with `setTransform` the position of canvas to "neutral"
And with `save` and `restore` you bring it back where fabricjs expects it to be,

in this way you will clip exactly from 0,0 to 700,700.

**UPDATE MARCH 2017**

If you are working with screen that have a devicepixelRatio bigger than 1 ( retina screens, mobile devices ) you may need different code:

```
object.clipTo = function (ctx) {
     var retina = fabric.getRetinaScaling();
     ctx.save();
     ctx.setTransform(retina,0,0,retina,0,0);
     ctx.rect(0, 0, 700, 700);
     ctx.restore();
};
```